# Facebook login with swift - import issue

Tags: swift, facebook-login

I am trying to do Facebook login with Swift.
I added the bridge header file to properly import Facebook code, but for some reason these classes are not recognized:

- FBSDKLoginManager
- FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult

Any idea why it happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you brought it in as a framework then you don't need to add it into your bridging header. Instead add "import FBSDKLoginKit" to the top of your swift file and it will recognize the classes.